# sending a http post from python to php

Tags: php, python

I am trying some basic program where I want to send a string as parameter from Python to PHP and to write the received data into a text file. But I am unable to receive the parameter in PHP. I'm getting an `undefined index in php` error and no data written into the text file.

Here is the Python code:

```
params=urllib.urlencode({"name":"hello"})
headers={"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencode","Accept": "text/plain"}
conn=httplib.HTTPConnection("localhost:80")
conn.request("POST","http://localhost/test.php",params)
response=conn.getresponse()
print response.status,response.reason
data=response.read()
print data
```

And the PHP code:

```
$a=$_POST['name'];
$myfile = fopen("n.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $a;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
echo $a;
```

Here is the output:

```
200 OK
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php</b> 
on line <b>4</b><br />
```